# ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry (but I haven't loaded package twice)

Tags: package-options

I am currently trying to create a landscape document using r markdown. Since I also want the header to be in landscape, I have the following mystyles.sty document:

```
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{,pdflscape}
```

which is called in the header of my main document:

```
---
title: "Transition Matrix Report for 2015-01-20"
author: "Paul Lintilhac"
date: "Monday, February 2, 2015"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyles.sty
---
```

however, when I try to knit the pdf, I get the error:

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.62 \usepackage

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc"     TransitionMatrix.utf8.md --to latex --from     markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures --output TransitionMatrix.pdf --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-31~1.2\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\default.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --include-in-header mystyles.sty --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
```

I have checked many forums online, and they all seem to say that this error occurrs because I have tried to load a package with options twice. But clearly this is not the case. I have checked line 62 in the tex document produced by r markdown, and it is the line after calling `usepackage[landscape]{geometry}`. Getting rid of the other packages in mystyles.sty has no effect, however, when I go to the top of the tex document, I can see several other packages that are getting loaded automatically, as you can see at the top of the tex document copied below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript

\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage[landscape,width=15in,height=11.5in,top=.5in,bottow=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{,pdflscape}
```

I get the same error if I remove any of these except for `\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}`
, which gives a different error.

What is going wrong here and how can I fix? Would really appreciate your help as I have been trying to get this stupid formatting correct for hours.

Best,

-Paul

Comment: Extra comma?! `\usepackage{,pdflscape}`

Comment: thanks for the comment, but as I said, removing the other packages from mystyles.sty has no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Please post a single complete example that generates the error. We can't debug code we can not see.  Start with a copy of the first 62 lines of the document and delete anything you can while still generating the error, then post the result.

Comment: sure, I just posted the minimum code that produces the error. I now see that there is a conflicting import of the geometry package, but I don't know what to do because this code is being automatically produced by r markdown.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=18769574#18769574

Comment: thank you for the comment, but the problem is not solved. It remains true that I did not load the package twice, and that I don't know why it was.

Comment: If you run latex on a document that has two `\usepackage` with the same package, by any normal reading you loaded the package twice. it may be you used a tool to generate a bad document but to be honest that's off topic for this site.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, if I understand it correctly, the document is created in R, and I think that's not off-topic. But the question is then badly stated as it doesn't reflect this problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

and

```
\usepackage[landscape,width=15in,height=11.5in,top=.5in,bottow=.5in]{geometry}
```

look like loading twice to me.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I realize that it is being loaded twice, but I did not do that myself -- it is just happening automatically. Any advice on how to stop that from happening?

Comment: @PaulNo idea sorry, I don't have experience of that generator so can't say whether you are giving it bad input, or it is doing it on its own so it's a bug. If you have access to the document preamble and can cause geometry to be loaded earlier, load it with all the options (I assume `bottow` is a typo for `bottom` by the way) then _both_ the current `\usepackage` will be ignored without error as they are using subsets of the initial option set.

Comment: @Paul: Your editor saw something shiny, was distracted, and then it magically thought to call `geometry` with a varied number of options... yes, so says my crystal ball Jeffrey... More serious though: your error points to line 62 as being a problem, while the minimal code doesn't have 62 lines. Why is that?

Comment: @Paul: As pandoc seems to load geometry you could simply write in your own style `\geometry{landscape,width=15in,height=11.5in,top=.5in,bottom=.5in}` to change the settings.